# add a Tab to Tab control with its content

Tags: c#

I am working on an ERP project. it is a button on treeView box and when it is clicking on a button in treeView it must create a Tab with its content (content which is defined-designed before).

I can add a tab programically  but how can I design its content?

Comment: What is the problem you're facing exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a new user control to the project then use the designer to do controls/layout, then when you click all you do is add a new instance of the user control to the tab - probably docked to fill the tab unless your form's size is fixed.

Comment: could you give some more detail please

Comment: See what @pondidum did (+1 there)

Answer (score 2):

Adding this to your click event of your treeview should do what you are after:

```
var contentControl = new ContentControl ();    //This is what we will put all your content in
contentControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

var page = new TabPage("Tab Text");    //the title of your new tab
page.Controls.Add(contentControl);     //add the content to the tab

TabControl1.TabPages.Add(page);        //add the tab to the tabControl
```

To your project, add a new `UserControl` called ContentControl (or whatever you need, just using this in my example), and fill it with all the contents you want to appear in your tab.

Answer (score 1):

You have few solutions, the simplest one is to create `TabPage`, create desired Controls, set up their properties (i.e. Size, Location, Text etc.), add them to the `TabPage` and then add `TabPage` to the `TabControl`.

```
TabPage tp = new TabPage();
//create controls and set their properties
Button btn1 = new Button();
btn1.Location = new Point(10,10);
btn1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(30,15);
//add control to the TabPage
tp.Controls.Add(btn1);
//add TabPage to the TabControl
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
```

the second solution is to override `TabPage` in your class, for instance `CustomTabPage` where you will set up controls in the constructor of the class. Then, when you want to add new `TabPage`, create your `CustomTabPage` instance and add it to the `TabControl`.

```
public class CustomTabPage : TabPage
{
    public CustomTabPage()
    {
        //create your Controls and setup their properties
        Button btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.Location = new Point(20, 20);
        btn1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(40, 20);
        //add controls to the CustomTabPage
        this.Controls.Add(btn1);
    }
}

//Create CustomTabPage
CustomTabPage ctp = new CustomTabPage();
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(ctp);
```

the third solution (the best but the most complicated) is to create your desired `UserControl` with everything you want on it (you can use Designer help), then create an instance of your `UserControl`, Create a `TabPage` and add `UserControl` on the `TabPage`. Then add `TabPage` to the `TabControl`.

```
 public partial class CustomControlForTabPage : UserControl
 {
     public CustomControlForTabPage()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }
 }

//Create CustomControl
TabPage tp = new TabPage();
CustomControlForTabPage ccftp = new CustomControlForTabPage();
//set properties you like for your custom control
tp.Controls.Add(ccftp);
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(ctp);
```